# Can I use AND (&&) OR ( || ) operators in dependency array React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I use `&&` and/or `||` operators in dependency array like this:

```
const isVisible = true
const isModified = false

useEffect(() => console.log("both are true"), [isVisible && isModified])
```

Is it a bad practice?
Eslint says `React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

How can I achieve the same result by doing this the right way?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to have the useEffect run when either one of the variables changes?

Comment: this is the first time i have seen someone use a logical operator in the dependency array.  if you could explain what you are trying to achieve, maybe a better solution could be provided.

Answer (score 5):

Eslint says lots of stuff. If this is your project and you like that style, change your .eslintrc so that it doesn't flag that. If you are coding to someone else's style, then you should respect it and maybe do:

```
const isVisible = true
const isModified = false

const combined = [isVisible && isModified]

useEffect(() => console.log("both are true"), combined)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, the code is totally independent, so, it'd be a good idea to remove dependency array.

In case if in the callback you conditionally do things with `isVisible` or `isModified`, it means that your code **depends on both of this variables**. In that case, you'll just need to specify both of them in the dependency array (`[isVisible, isModified]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the expected result by checking the state of `isVisible` and `isModified` within the `useEffect` callback function. Please look at the following example

```
const isVisible = true;
const isModified = false;

useEffect(() => {
  if (isVisible && isModified) {
    console.log("both are true");
  }
}, [isVisible, isModified]);
```

Comment: Doesn’t the if condition cause many renders? I think the ‘&&’ operator works well instead of an if.